# Cannot open the datefile when running a scheduled ssis package. SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssis

So I have researched this problem thoroughly, or so I think. I want to schedule an upload of a CSV to our database in SQL Server.  I have created the SSIS package using tasks --> import data.  When I initially create and run the package it works fine.  However, when I want to schedule the package to run I run into an error.  "Cannot open the datafile "C:\Users\mydomainaccount\CsvToUpload.csv"  The file is saved locally on my laptop, however, the ultimate goal is to have the source be a mapped drive where our CSV files are.

This is what I have do so far to trouble shoot:

When creating the package I have saved the SSIS package using both the SQL Server option and the File System option, both will work initially running the package, but neither work when attempting to schedule the job.  Also, for protection level I have tried the Encrypt sensitive data password and the do not save sensitive data options.

I checked and made sure that SYSTEM has full control of the folder and file where the package and csv are located.

The job step is being run as a proxy account that I created, I have also tried running it as the SQL Server Agent Service Account.

The owner of the job is my domain account.  My account has sysadmin privileges for that database and server.  Under the msdb database option I have given my account SQLAgentOperator, Reader, and User Roles.  the NT Service\SQLAgent and NT Service\MSSQL accounts have those same roles and sysadmin privileges.

So basically, I know the package will run, it is just when scheduled and seems to have some sort of permissions issue that is not allowing it to run.  Any help or suggestions would be great!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqZWb.png

Comment: What happens when you open the file saved in the root directory (C:\CsvToUpload.csv)?

Comment: Is there anything in the package other than the data flow task?

Comment: Shiv- I just moved the file to be right on the C: drive and updated the package.  I still get the same error message.

Comment: Eric-I created the task in SQL server not via visual studio so I assume the only thing in the package is a data flow.  All it does is goes to the file and puts it in the data base in SQL Server, if there is already data it will delete the rows and add in the new data.

Comment: Are you sure that file extensions are enabled, that is, your file is indeed not C:\CsvToUpload.csv.csv. To make sure check folder options -> View and check uncheck the hide file extensions box.

Comment: Just checked, and the file is just .csv    not .csv.csv

Comment: Please share screenshot of your ssis file connection. Your integration services are running locally on your laptop  and SQL Server Agent is running on your laptop as well, the file is on the laptop too! Theres got to be an issue with the way connection is configured.

Comment: Where would I find my ssis file connection?  Is this what you are looking for?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqZWb.png

Comment: Move the file to a shared folder and use that network path in your connection. grant permissions to Integration Services Account and Sql Agent Account to new network path. It almost appears as if you 'think' you have deployed the package to your local sql server but its actually deployed to some remote box.